# Forms created on VS2008 .net framework changes on another PC

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am writing a program on a desktop PC with screen size of 2560x1440 using Visual Studio 2008. I copied this program to Microsoft Surface Pro 3 with the screen resolution of 2160x1440.
I fixed the form size to 1800x974 and expected to be fit on my Surface Pro 3.
But, when I opened the project file on the surface pro 3, the form size changed to 1456x958.
How can I fix this problem? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's just the form's AutoScaleMode property doing its work, adjusting the layout to the video adapter's dots-per-inch setting.  Don't fix it, it ain't broken.